# Ionic App is not connecting to Node API using the Android Emulator or Phone

Tags: android, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, mean-stack

I am creating an ionic app using the MEAN Stack. I am using MongoLabs for the database, and my node server is at `localhost:8080`. My Endpoints (My login functionality) are working fine in the browser when I use `"ionic serve"` or `"ionic serve --lab"`. The port for Ionic by default is set on 8100, which is what I am using.

When I run `ionic emulate android` to use an emulator or `ionic run android` to see the app on my phone, the app shows up just fine (the login pages), but none of the functionality works (which are the endpoints from my node API).

Do I need to set the node port to something else? Would this be caused from node being on localhost, and if so, what do I change it too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sure is because of localhost, you cannot access localhost from emulator. Get the IP address of your machine and use it. e.g. 192.168.1.102 or 10.0.x.x check your IP with ipconfig/ifconfig based on Windows/Unix respectively.

Comment: Thanks for that. For production, how would each user connect to the api? Would I need to host the api somewhere, or is there a way that each user hits the api directly from the app using their ip address?

Comment: Yes you need to host the API.